# WPF binding errors when updating dynamic datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have dynamic Datagrid where columns creating programmatically and assigning items. After update I'm getting binding errors and I don't know how avoid them,
It seems that the styles are binded to Items in Visual tree and when updating items the triggers running on orphan data

```
    <local:PerBalanceReportDataGrid Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent" Panel.ZIndex="1000"
                                                    FrozenColumnCount="1"
                                                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                                    ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="PerBalanceReportDataGrid_ScrollChanged"
                                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                                    ColumnWidth="150"
                                                    x:Name="PerBalanceReportDataGrid" >
                        <local:PerBalanceReportDataGrid.CellStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource textToColorConverter}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource textToBoldConverter}}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </local:PerBalanceReportDataGrid.CellStyle>
                        <local:PerBalanceReportDataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Style>
                        </local:PerBalanceReportDataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <local:PerBalanceReportDataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </Style>
                        </local:PerBalanceReportDataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                        </local:PerBalanceReportDataGrid>
```

```
    public class ExtendedDataGrid<TDynamicRowType, TCellDataType> : DataGrid where TDynamicRowType : DynamicDataRow<TCellDataType>
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataTableProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "DataTable",
                typeof(DataTable<TDynamicRowType, TCellDataType>),
                typeof(ExtendedDataGrid<TDynamicRowType, TCellDataType>),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnDataTablePropertyChanged));

        public DataTable<TDynamicRowType, TCellDataType> DataTable
        {
            get { return (DataTable<TDynamicRowType, TCellDataType>)GetValue(DataTableProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataTableProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnDataTablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is ExtendedDataGrid<TDynamicRowType, TCellDataType> grid)
                grid.Init();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            if (DataTable == null)
                return;

            ItemsSource = null;
            Columns.Clear();
            SetValue(DataGridReadOnlyBehavior<TDynamicRowType>.PredicateProperty, DataTable.IsReadOnlyPredicate);
            Columns.AddRange(DataTable.Columns.Select(FromInfo));
            ItemsSource = DataTable.Rows;

            ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource);
            view.GroupDescriptions.AddRange(
                DataTable.GroupByProperties.Select(x => new PropertyGroupDescription(x)));

            ExtendedColumn<TCellDataType> FromInfo(ColumnInfo info) => new (info);
        }
    }

    public class PerBalanceReportDataGrid : ExtendedDataGrid<PerBalanceReportDataRow, string>
    {
        static PerBalanceReportDataGrid() =>
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(PerBalanceReportDataGrid),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PerBalanceReportDataGrid)));
    }
```

After I'm updating the table I'm getting the following errors

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Foreground; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush')

[image]

Comment: Hi, please post the error as text. You can use this [edit] link to [edit] your question.

Comment: And one more thing when opening page(Initializing component) table don't have any columns and data. Data and columns are loading when user clicks one of listview items